# ASP.NET - Is it possible to block cookies declaratively in an aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

can cookies be blocked using a page directive instead of doing it programmatic?

Comment: By block do you mean the page will refuse to send cookies or refuse to accept cookies?

Comment: Maybe you mean that you want to use cookieless sessions?

Comment: i want a page to not accept cookies, for ex: we can use something like cookie.discard programmatic but is it possible declaratively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, AFAIK,  there is no way to do anything with respect to cookies declaratively other than force HttpsOnly or to choose cookieless Sessions. "Not accepting" makes no sense given how cookies work. Is it that you are trying to expire the existing cookies? If so, again, you must do this programatically.

Answer (score 2):

Why?  If you don't want the cookies, just don't use them.  You can't stop the browser from sending cookies to the server; but you can simply not use them.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with thomas. If you are gunning for the session cookie, then disable session.  The server will stop sending session cookies to the browser and the browser will stop returning them on subsequent requests.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306996

If you are trying to engage in industrial sabotage or some heavy handed security, i.e. treating all http requests with cookies as invalid requests, then

```
if (Request.Cookies.Count > 0)
{
     throw new HttpException(
    "Keep your stinking cookies.  I accept request only browsers"+
    " configured to disable the sending of cookies.");
}
```

If you are trying to ignore cookies or to figure out why the app you maintain results in cookies (usually auth or some state managment), then search your source code for these and comment them out.

- Request.Cookies, Requests.Cookies.Add()
- Session  (can
  still work with cookie-less sessions,
  where session Id is in the URL)
- Membership  (can still work with
  cookie-less sessions, where auth
  token is in the URL)

Comment: +1 For the HttpException message - I'd give you another +1 for the answer if I could!

Answer (score 0):

After reading through the [43 separate page directive attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx) I don't reckon that you can block cookies using a page directive (i.e. using the <%@ Page attribute="value" [attribute="value"...] %> syntax).

Comment: I honestly don't know what motivates downvotes as this answer appears to precisely answer the question.  If my answer is wrong could someone explain why?   Not agreeing with an answer is not a reason to downvote - only if it is fundamentally flawed.

Comment: the link was not working but it's working now, weird unless you edited it.

Comment: No I've not touched the link - perhaps MSDN was briefly playing up?

Comment: - that could very well have been the case.